# Lombok with mixed Android/non-Android project in Android Studio 1.5

Tags: android, intellij-lombok-plugin

I have a new Android project that will be making use of an existing communication library.  I expect to have to modify the library to support the Android app, so I've imported it as a module.

The Lombok instructions for Android Studio seem to require using the Android gradle plugin.  My library uses the Java plugin.  Without that android plugin, Lombok doesn't seem to work in Android Studio (getters and setters aren't resolved).

If I want Lombok to work with my existing library in the same project, do I have to modify the library to build as an Android library rather than a simple jar?

More generally, am I creating a world of pain by trying to build a non-Android library module in an Android project?

### Library build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src'
            exclude '**/ticketfx/**.java'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'res'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/lombok.jar')
    compile files('libs/protobuf-java-j7.jar')
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This mysteriously started working with no additional effort in Android Studio 1.5.  My solution: upgrade!